# Log LogEventInfo is not writing the correct information

Tags: c#, nlog

I created a dictionary with test data and I wanted to log it with LogEventInfo. However, it wrote my desk name on the console instead of the correct information.

```
    public void LogDebugWithAdditionalFields(string logMessage, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        LogEventInfo logInfo = new LogEventInfo();
        logInfo.Level = LogLevel.Debug;

        foreach (var dataItem in data)
        {
            logInfo.Properties.Add(dataItem.Key, dataItem.Value);
        }

        var logger = GetLoggerFullName();
        logger.Log(logInfo);
    }

    public Logger GetLoggerFullName()
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().FullName);
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot set the correct layout. it should include `${event-properties:item=String}` in the layout.

See [here.](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer)